# Flask proxy response for file download

Tags: python, flask, proxy

I am using a Flask route as a proxy to download a file, like this:

```
@esa_handler.route("/data/<int:series>/<int:file_num>", methods=["GET"])
def DownloadRemote(series, file_num):
    """
    Downloads the remote files from the ESA.
    :param series: 0-20.
    :param file_num: File within the series, 0-255
    :return: Compressed CSV file.
    """

    # if the file is bad.
    if series >= 20 and file_num > 110:
        return jsonify({"error": "file does not exist."})

    url = "http://cdn.gea.esac.esa.int/Gaia/gaia_source/csv/GaiaSource_000-{:03d}-{:03d}.csv.gz".format(series,
                                                                                                        file_num)
    req = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    return Response(stream_with_context(req.iter_content(chunk_size=2048)), content_type=req.headers["content-type"])
```

It works fine, however, the filename that is presented to the client is whatever the file number that is passed to the endpoint. For example, if I put `http://127.0.0.1:5000/esa/data/0/0` to download the very first file, it downloads, but Chrome/Firefox/IE/Edge are offering to save the file with a filename as "0". While there is nothing wrong with that, I would like a better user experience.

How can I intercept the response to proffer a filename based off the URL requested?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) HTTP header. Here you can specify a filename for the newly downloaded file.

This can be added to a Flask [`Response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.response_class) as follows:

```
url = "http://cdn.gea.esac.esa.int/Gaia/gaia_source/csv/GaiaSource_000-{:03d}-{:03d}.csv.gz".format(series,
req = requests.get(url, stream=True)

headers = Headers()
headers .add('Content-Type', req.headers["content-type"])
headers .add('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="filename.txt"')

return Response(stream_with_context(req.iter_content(chunk_size=2048)), headers=headers)
```

*Note: The `Content-Type` was moved into `headers` for simplicity*

Comment: If `req.headers['Content-Disposition']` is available, you can directly use it in your response's headers. I.e.: `headers.add('Content-Disposition', req.headers['Content-Disposition'])`